# How can you force eclipse to perform createPartControl() on a stacked view

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a view that is stacked behind another view on creation. It is supposed to listen for an event and bring itself to the front and populate some data if that data gets set.

However becasue the createPartControl method doesn't get called until the user actually brings it to the front the functionality doesn't work how I'd like,

Is there a way to tell the rcp application that it should instantiate that view on load up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with Indigo or Juno and you're developing an RCP application, have you tried one of the methods available on IWorkbenchPage (like activate(…) or showView(…)) ? Basically, knowing your view ID (as defined in the plugin.xml), you can add this code to the postWindowOpen() method of your application WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, so that it is called once the window is opened.